# Wireshark Lua API: How to get TCP header info?

Tags: lua, wireshark, wireshark-dissector

I'm writing a dissector <sup>(to be added to `DissectorTable.get("tcp.port")`)</sup> for a TCP-based application. I've gone through the Wireshark API [doc](https://www.wireshark.org/docs/wsdg_html_chunked/wsluarm_modules.html) but could not find out how to get TCP header's info like

- SYN/ACK flags
- Sequence number
- ACK'ed sequence number

---

**UPDATE:**

Based on the answer I'd put example snippet here. Just FYI.

```lua
local proto = Proto("myproto", "my proto")

-- ...
-- ...

--
-- A Field object can only be created *outside* of the callback
-- functions of dissectors, post-dissectors, heuristic-dissectors,
-- and taps.
--
local F_tcp_seq_rel = Field.new('tcp.seq')      -- relative seq num
local F_tcp_seq_raw = Field.new('tcp.seq_raw')  -- raw seq num

function proto.dissector(tvbuf, pinfo, tree)

    -- ...
    -- ...

    local seq_rel = F_tcp_seq_rel()  -- yes the Field object is callable!
    local seq_raw = F_tcp_seq_raw()

    -- ...
    -- ...
end

DissectorTable.get("tcp.port"):add(12345, proto)
```

Comment: Do you mean you're writing a dissector for a protocol that uses TCP as the transport protocol and that you're not actually writing a dissector for TCP itself, as you indicated?  Well, assuming so, why do you need TCP SYN/ACK flags, sequence and ACK numbers at all?  

If you're looking for an example of Lua dissector for a TCP-based protocol, then you might want to refer to the `fpm.lua` file available under the [A dissector tutorial with TCP-reassembly](https://gitlab.com/wireshark/wireshark/-/wikis/Lua/Examples#a-dissector-tutorial-with-tcp-reassembly) section of the Lua examples wiki page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way to get any field data, TCP or otherwise, is via a [Field Extractor](https://www.wireshark.org/docs/wsdg_html/#lua_class_Field).  So for example:

```
local tcp_flags_syn = Field.new("tcp.flags.syn")
local tcp_flags_ack = Field.new("tcp.flags.ack")

-- If you want relative sequence/acknowledgment numbers:
local tcp_seq = Field.new("tcp.seq")
local tcp_ack = Field.new("tcp.ack")

-- If you want absolute sequence/acknowledgment numbers:
local tcp_seq_raw = Field.new("tcp.seq_raw")
local tcp_ack_raw = Field.new("tcp.ack_raw")
```

If you need additional help using these fields, you may want to look at some of the Lua examples provided on the Wireshark [Examples](https://gitlab.com/wireshark/wireshark/-/wikis/Lua/Examples) and/or [Contrib](https://gitlab.com/wireshark/wireshark/-/wikis/Contrib) wiki pages.